# Why is a Birth Rate of 2.1 Needed to Prevent Population Decline?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have read in many places, assuming no immigration/emigration and constant birth/death rates:  A **Birth Rate of 2.1** is needed to prevent the population from declining (e.g. https://data.oecd.org/pop/fertility-rates.htm)

[image]
**I was trying to understand, where does this number 2.1 come from?**

I tried to write something myself : $P_0$ is the initial population, $P(t)$ is the population at time t, $b$ is the birth rate, $d$ is the death rate, $c$ is the constant of integration

Is it possible to write a series of differential equations and understand this?

I tried to do it myself:

$$ \text{Original Equation: } \frac{dP(t)}{dt} = (b - d)P(t)$$

Here is the Exact Solution:

$$\frac{dP(t)}{dt} = (b-d)P(t)$$
$$\frac{dP(t)}{P(t)} = (b-d)dt $$
$$\int \frac{1}{P(t)} dt = \int (b-d)dt $$
$$ln(P(t)) = (b-d)t + \text{integration constant} $$
$$P(t) = \exp((b-d)t + c) $$
$$P(t) = \exp((b-d)t) + c$$

Here is the Approximate Solution:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dP(t)}{dt} &= (b-d)P(t) \\
\frac{P(t + \Delta t) - P(t)}{\Delta t} &= (b-d)P(t) \\
P(t + \Delta t) - P(t) &= [(b-d)P(t)]\Delta t \\
P(t + \Delta t) &= [(b-d)P(t)]\Delta t + P(t) \\
P(t + \Delta t) &= P(t)[(b-d)\Delta t + 1]
\end{align*}

Now, if we take $P(t + \Delta t) = P(t)[(b-d)\Delta t + 1]$, we can define the following recursive relationships:

\begin{align*}
\text{if } \Delta t = 1 \text{ and } t=0, & \quad P(1) = P(0)[ (b-d)+1] \\
\text{if } \Delta t =1 \text{ and } t =1, & \quad P(2) = P(1) [(b-d) +1]  = P(0) [(b-d)+1][(b-d)+1] = P(0) [(b-d)+1]^2  \\
\text{if } \Delta t = 1 \text{ and } t=n, & \quad P(n) = P(0) [(b-d) + 1]^n
\end{align*}

**But I am not sure how this number of 2.1 is derived, i.e. under the assumptions of no immigration/emigration and constant birth/death rates, why is a birth rate of 2.1 needed to prevent population decline?**

Thanks!

Comment: I think $2.1$ was for them a crude way of saying "greater than $2$".

Comment: I think women who don't live till the end of their child-bearing years are treated differently in the definition of fertility rate.

Comment: A large part of that will be child mortality. A smaller contribution should come from the male-female imbalance at birth.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia Wiki article on [Total fertility rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_fertility_rate), the replacement rate (the number of births per woman to maintain population with no net migration) is $2.1$ for most developed countries but can be as high as $3.5$ in underdeveloped countries because of high mortality rates, especially infant mortality.  So evidently one must take mortality rates into account in the analysis.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies everyone!